# Does using a CDN prevent Intellisense from working for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, intellisense, javascript-intellisense, vsdoc

I read in "jQuery for ASP.NET Developers" this re: getting Intellisense support in VS for jQuery: "....a VSDoc file for jQuery...The VSDoc file...uses the same name as your JavaScript file with -vsdoc inserted before the .js file extension. For example, if my jQuery file is called jQuery-1.3.2.js, then the vsdoc file would be called jQuery-1.3.2-vsdocjs. the VSDoc file must exist in the same directory as your jQuery file so that VS can find it."

Does this mean that using a CDN for jQuery files prevents Intellisense from working?

Comment: I should hope this is only the case for local JS files, not remote ones. Have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a CDN and still have Intellisense support in Visual Studio. There are two ways to do this:

1. Add an Intellisense reference to the `*vsdoc.js` file that is hosted
   on the CDN. Go to `Tools | Options`:

   [image: Options dialog]

   Note that you will need to make an entry for *each* `*vsdoc.js` that
   you want to use.
2. If you know that the `*vsdoc.js` file is co-located in the same directory with the `js` file on the CDN (like it is on the ASP.NET CDN), *AND* you're using MVC, you can just update your `_references.js` file to reflect this:

`/// <reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.js" />`

If you need help with _references.js, see my blog entry [here](http://windowshell.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/javascript-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2012/).

Be sure to update your webpage (or _Layout.cshtml) reference to actually use the CDN too.  Note that the `js` path that you use for your web pages doesn't have to be the same as your Intellisense reference (of course, you obviously want them to be the same version)!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <script src="@Url.Content("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts")
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: The examples above assume that you're not using ASP.NET 4.5 bundling, or taking advantage of CDN features such as path mirroring and reverse proxies.  I assume that if you're using these features, you know what needs to be done to get them running.

Comment: Since I've never of ASP.NET 4.5 bundling, path mirroring or reverse proxies, I'm probably safe that way (ignorance is bliss, they say). However (alas!), I have no JavaScript entry in my Tools | Options tree.

Comment: What version of VS are you running?

Comment: My example is from 2012, but I think the menu options are still the same. I just looked at my screen snap and realized the path is not clear. In the Options dialog, drill down to Text Editor | JavaScript | Intellisense | References. You should find it there.

Comment: No, I have a Text Editor | JScript, but no JavaScript, and no Intellisense below JScript.

Comment: Argh, it appears VS 2010 does JavaScript Intellisense differently than 2012. Unfortunately, since I don't have that version installed, I'm afraid that I will be of little help to you.